# Unity - adding camera constraint to prevent the player from seeing beyond the scene

Tags: unity, c#, camera, skybox

Like the title says, I'm after some kind of constraint for the camera to prevent the player from seeing beyond the scene and seeing the Skybox. I came across the code to add a `Mathf.Clamp`, but I can't get it to work.
I'm currently trying to make a 2.5D platformer in which the camera follows the player (ahead), which leads to seeing beyond the scene to the far left and right. I already have an invisible wall in place to prevent the player from falling off, but I would love to also clamp the camera from going any further.

This is the script I have at the moment:

````cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] GameObject player = null;
    [SerializeField] [Range(0.1f, 2f)] float followAhead = 2f;
    [SerializeField] [Range(0.1f, 2f)] float smoothing = 1f;

    //public PlayerController playerController;

    private float minPosition = -9.37f;
    private float maxPosition = 4.68f;
    private Vector3 cameraClamp;

    const float m_minY = 2f;
    Vector3 targetPosition;
    Vector3 cameraOffset;

    void Start()
    {
        cameraOffset = transform.position - player.transform.position;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        targetPosition = (player.transform.position + (player.transform.forward * followAhead)) + cameraOffset;
        //smoothedForward = Vector3.MoveTowards(smoothedForward, playerController.GetTravelDirection(), 0.5f * Time.deltaTime);
        //targetPosition = (player.transform.position + (smoothedForward * followAhead));
        //transform.position = player.transform.position + cameraOffset;
        targetPosition.y = Mathf.Min(targetPosition.y, m_minY);
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetPosition, smoothing * Time.deltaTime);
        cameraClamp.x = Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, -9.37f, 4.68f);
    }
}
```
````

Comment: did you try to slove your problem with colliders?

Comment: I haven't, but I'll try looking into them. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

When clamping the camera to your bounds, you want to make sure to re-assign the position like so:

```
// Set these in the inspector to tune your bounds.
public Vector3 MinCamPosition;
public Vector3 MaxCamPosition;


void Update()
{
    transform.position = new Vector3(
        Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, MinCamPosition.x, MaxCamPosition.x),
        Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y, MinCamPosition.y, MaxCamPosition.y), 
        Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.z, MinCamPosition.z, MaxCamPosition.z)
    ); 
}
```

Or you can use `Vector3.Min`/`Max` to express this more concisely:

```
    transform.position = Vector3.Max(
        MinCamPosition,
        Vector3.Min(MaxCamPosition, transform.position)
    );
```